# Fetching td value in php file and sending back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm facing an issue to get the value of td when a link is clicked

search_code.php

```
echo "<table class='table table-hover'>";
echo "<tr><th>Institute ID</th><th>Institute Name</th><th>State</th><th>District</th><th>City</th><th>General Seats</th><th>Reserved Seats</th></tr>";

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td id='instid'>".$row["collegeUniqueId"]."</td><td id='instname'><a href='#' onClick='getCourses(".$row["collegeUniqueId"].");'>".$row["name"]."</a></td><td>".$row["state"]."</td><td>".$row["district"]."</td><td>".$row["city"]."</td><td>".$row["openSeat"]."</td><td>".$row["reservedSeat"]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

and in search.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'search_code.php?state=' + $('#state').val() + '&district=' + $('#district').val(),
                success: function(institute){
                    $('#institute').html(institute);
                }
            });
        });

        function getCourses(id) {
            $id = id;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'courses.php?courseid=' + id,
                success: function(courses){
                    $('#courses').html(courses);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have more than one DOM element with a given `id` value. Your loop is creating multiple elements with the same `id`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the HTML that gets produced, but if the "ID" value is anything other than a *number*, you need to put it in quotes:

```
echo "...onClick='getCourses(\"".$row["collegeUniqueId"]."\");'>...";
// --------------------------^^---------------------------^^
```

---

Side note: You'll also want to deal with those repeated `id` values the loop creates (assuming there's ever more than one row in the result set).

---

Side note 2: You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in your `getCourses` function: You never declare the `$id` variable. You can just remove it, you're not using it for anything.

Answer (score 0):

ID in HTML needs to be unique you can't have multiple elements with same ID.

There are at least 2 ways to fix it:

1. Use class attribute and use data-id attribute to get ID of particular row
2. In your PHP you can generate id with ROW id `<td id='instid-".$row["collegeUniqueId"]."'>`

Comment: While this is true ([as I mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977566/fetching-td-value-in-php-file-and-sending-back/30977675#comment49985595_30977566)), surprisingly, it's unlikely to be the actual problem if you look at the code, as the OP doesn't seem to be trying to use those `id`s (at least, not in relation to the code in the question).

Comment: Yep there are more problems like binding events after AJAX is loaded for example or preventing default event behavior.